# Should we get questions from Reddit and the forums?

Tags: discussion

There are probably some questions on Reddit and the forums that have been asked more than once, and that have specific answers. Is it good protocol to go and get those, and the good answers and put them here, or should we let those who asked them do that? If you do the former then you could be seen as increasing your reputation figure (if you care about such things) while other people have put in the work asking and answering.

Comment: Answering a Reddit question here and then providing a link to the solution on Reddit would be especially useful for newbie questions.

Answer (score 19):

- **Attribute**
  If you're going to directly copy (and you're not the original author) then make sure you use the Markdown quote syntax (precede lines of quoted text with a `>`) and link to the original post. Plagiarism (or perceived plagiarism) is *seriously* frowned upon in a Stack Exchange site. Something like this should work:

  > This question was asked on Reddit a while ago:
  >
  > > lorem ipsum; here is the answer in a quote; ipsum lorem
  > >     <sub>— [Reddit](http://reddit.com)</sub>

  The Markdown source for that is:

  ```
  This question was asked on Reddit a while ago:

  > lorem ipsum; here is the answer in a quote; ipsum lorem  
  > <sub>&mdash; [Reddit](http://reddit.com)</sub>
  ```

  Note that the quoted line is appended with two spaces, to create a linebreak.
- **Don't just link**
  If you ask or answer a question that's been asked before anywhere else, don't *just* link to that - if the link dies, or the website goes down, then suddenly nobody can access the question or answer any more. Quote and attribute the important parts; add your own analysis if you can or feel it's necessary.

Apart from that, taking the (good quality) questions from other Ethereum communities and posting them here is an excellent idea, because it'll give you a kick start with good quality stuff. Make sure you're interspersing them with original questions, though.

Comment: This is already, IMO, the correct answer.  Would you give an example of, dare I say, a 'citation format'?

Comment: @NewAlexandria How's that do you?

Comment: I've already upvoted, but I would upvote again.  I remember reading someone suggesting to print the name of the reddit user who asked (while still linking to the question).   That's an option, too.